# Why does this code run slower and slower?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an entity class called `SrcFile` and one of its columns is:

```
@NotNull
@Lob
private Byte[] data;
```

This `SrcFile` has a OneToOne relationship with Report entity.

From Report.java:

```
@OneToOne
private SrcFile srcFile;
```

Persisting a `SrcFile` entity works great.

`````````````````
srcFileHomeFacade.clearInstance();
SrcFile srcFile = srcFileHomeFacade.getInstance();
byte[] bArray = resource.getBytesForSource();
srcFile.setData(ReportFileResource.toObject(bArray));
System.out.println("````````````````srcFile data length: "+bArray.length);
srcFileHomeFacade.persist();
`````````````````

The problem comes when I persist `Report`.

I do:

```
report.setSrcFile(srcFile);
reportHomeFacade.persist();
```

and works nice BUT **after running this code multiple times it gets slower and slower** (even it raises GC overhead error) and after hours of investigation I discovered that this `report.setSrcFile(srcFile)` is the problem.

Somehow report does not like to reference such amount of `srcFile.data`...

Do you see the cause?

If I comment `report.setSrcFile` all works great (except that SRCFILE_ID in report table will be null, but it's just for testing). Please note that the length of data is about 100.000.

**Note**: If I not persist any `report` but only `srcFile` entities I have no problems.
**UPDATE**:

*"Run slower and slower"* explanations: this code is called for converting some pcls to pdfs so `data` contains the source of the pcl and it's different each time. After converting about 100 pcls the process goes slower and slower and with VM I discovered this byte[] arrays which takes a lot of MB memory. Again, it's definitely not a problem about IO but about this setSrcFile on report entity, VisualVM also indicates this.

Comment: I'd say because it's Java</troll> :p

Comment: Please clarify: What you mean when you say "run multiple times": Do you persist the same entity multiple times? Does the program run slower only when persisting or also when reading data?  Do you run read operations while writing the data? Do you set different files on the same report, or is it always one and the same srcFile for one report? Do you set CascadeTypes? Do you use lazy or eager loading?

Comment: @weltraumpirat I've just updated the question. I have not specified any cascade type on the entity fields. I just posted them here like I have in my source code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am still a bit unsure, but I suspect your problem relates to the way you are persisting things and handle the entity objects:  If you discard your entities properly once they are persisted, GC should free up memory often enough to keep your system running smoothly.  Especially if you use flush() or commit() after each transaction, your memory usage should not keep building up much at all.  In your case, though, it seems that all the entities are kept in memory even after they are no longer needed - so there has to be some reason why the resources are not released.

Do you by any chance use a single for loop to iterate over a set of srcFiles and have all the persist() calls directly within that?  If so, your problem might be related to scope.  You could try to extract the contents of the loop to a new method to have all local variables properly freed up after each iteration.

You might also be able to improve things by setting CascadeType.PERSIST or CascadeType.ALL and using a single persist() operation on the report to save both objects. FetchType.LAZY might help, as well.

In any case: Look for possible reasons why your program would keep all the entities directly available in memory, instead of saving them to the database and forgetting about them afterwards.

Comment: Sounds a very plausible possibility given the lack of detail in the question

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I'm using seam and I annotate the method which does this persist stuff with @Transactional so all the management for transaction and releasing the components is done by Seam... I will try with CascadeType.PERSIST.

Comment: It's AWESOME. It works with CascadeType.PERSIST and FetchType.LAZY ...Does this mean that after persisting the report, if the report is still in memory the srcFile not be detached by it? If yes, than all makes sense, because srcFile it's very huge....

Answer (score 0):

I remember native JDBC interface to BLOBs can be tricky and manual close() of vendor objects was required. If this step is missed the BLOBs were accumulated on JDBC driver (i.e. in JVM memory) and eventually JVM went OOM.

I wonder if you need any vendor-specific properties or steps to do to close BLOBs after save.